# Why are the name repeating in my array, and how would i get a txt file to sort

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, visual-c++

AfterI input scores and names for the test , the output creates 
repeating names , ex. I imput erick,derick,john,dick

The output would probably read erick , derick, derick, derick

I am also not sure how i would modify this program to open a txt file to
sort the data?

```
    //  main.cpp
    //  Program 9.4


    #include <iostream>

    #include<string>
    using namespace std;

    void sortScore(int *, int, string*);

    int main()
    {
        int numberOfStudents;
        cout << "Enter the number of students: " << endl;
        cin >> numberOfStudents;

        int* score = new int[numberOfStudents];
        string* nameOfStudent = new string[numberOfStudents];

        for (int i = 0; i<numberOfStudents; i++)
        {
            cout << "\nEnter Student " << i + 1 << "'s name: " << endl;
            cin >> nameOfStudent[i];
            cout << "\nEnter his/her score: " << endl;
            cin >> score[i];
        }

        sortScore(score, numberOfStudents, nameOfStudent);

        cout << "\nStudent Scores organized from lowest to highest:" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i<numberOfStudents; i++)
        {
            cout << "\n" << nameOfStudent[i] << "\t\t" << score[i];
        }

        cout << endl;

        delete[] score;
        score = 0;

        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }

    void sortScore(int *score, int size, string* name)
    {
        int startScan, minIndex;
        int minValue;
        string minName;

        for (startScan = 0; startScan<(size - 1); startScan++)
        {
            minIndex = startScan;
            minValue = score[startScan];

            for (int index = startScan + 1; index<size; index++)
            {
                if (score[index]<minValue)
                {
                    minValue = score[index];
                    minIndex = index;
                    minName = name[index];
                }
            }
            score[minIndex] = score[startScan];
            score[startScan] = minValue;
            name[minIndex] = name[startScan];
            name[startScan] = minName;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I recommend using `std::vector` over raw pointers. I see you've forgotten to free the memory for `nameOfStudent`. I also suggest combining the name and score into a data structure and then keeping track of one dynamic array instead of two.

Comment: Can't [reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1585fefbb4d5325e).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a logical error here and when there is no exchanged needed, you are actually exchanging with wrong information (losing the minName).

try this:

```
    for (startScan = 0; startScan<(size - 1); startScan++)
    {
        minIndex = startScan;
        minValue = score[startScan];

        for (int index = startScan + 1; index<size; index++)
        {
            if (score[index]<minValue)
            {
                minValue = score[index];
                minIndex = index;
                minName = name[index];
            }
        }
        if(minIndex != startScan) {
          score[minIndex] = score[startScan];
          score[startScan] = minValue;
          name[minIndex] = name[startScan];
          name[startScan] = minName; 
       }
    }
```

Or you have to carry the minName:

```
    for (startScan = 0; startScan<(size - 1); startScan++)
    {
        minIndex = startScan;
        minValue = score[startScan];
        minName  = name[startScan]; 
        for (int index = startScan + 1; index<size; index++)
        {
            if (score[index]<minValue)
            {
                minValue = score[index];
                minIndex = index;
                minName = name[index];
            }
        }
        score[minIndex] = score[startScan];
        score[startScan] = minValue;
        name[minIndex] = name[startScan];
        name[startScan] = minName; 
     }
```

Comment: thank you !!!, this is what i was looking for , i just couldn't figure it out, if it wouldn't be a big bother, how would i go about opening the info from a text file

Comment: You can read the text info to the array and sort it using ifstream. If you have problems, post your code and sample data of your text file so people can help.